# Series.astype creates a copy when copy=False but dtype is different

Tags: python, pandas

I encountered following behaviour

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2])
s2 = s1.astype('int64', copy=False)
s2[0] = 10
s1  # note that s1[0] has changed too

0    10
1     2
dtype: int64
```

where as by changing one to decimal

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2.0])
s2 = s1.astype('int64', copy=False)
s2[0] = 10
s1  # note that s1[0] is expected to change ,but does not

0    1.0
1    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Just by changing one value to decimal Python
ignores the assignment and type conversion !

Did I spent Months learning this unreliable stuff !!!

Comment: Is `copy=False` intentional?

Comment: doesnot make a difference

Comment: It's weird that there was no error raised when `s1.dtype != s2.dtype and copy == False`. Perhaps this should be a bug report.

Comment: @SunilChandras it does make a difference, in the first case.  It will make a copy and not affect `s1`.  In the 2nd case `int64` and `float64` have different binary representation, and a copy is made regardless.  It does seem like an error should be raised if a copy must be made.  `copy=False` is silently ignored in the 2nd case.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I meant it does not make a difference in problem statement

Answer (score 3):

This is not due to Python's behaviour, this is pandas.

[From the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

> be very careful setting `copy=False` as changes to values then **may** propagate to other pandas objects

(Emphasis mine.)

The difference is due to [these lines](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e8093ba372f9adfe79439d90fe74b0b5b6dea9d6/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L1032-L1034):

```
if is_dtype_equal(self.dtype, dtype):
     # Ensure that self.astype(self.dtype) is self
     return self.copy() if copy else self
```

It's clear that the intended behaviour for `astype` to re-use the underlying data rather than make a copy. With a different dtype, pandas can't always just re-use the data (because it's different -- an int64 with the value of 2 will not have the same binary representation as a float64 with the value of 2.0).

Comment: copy=True gives exactly same results

Comment: @SunilChandras because a copy has to be made if the types are different and `copy=False` is ignored as the code quoted shows.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two is that `.astype()` doesn't need to convert the type, if it's already in that type, when you use `copy=False`.

When you do this:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2])
s2 = s1.astype('int64', copy=False)
```

you now have two `Series` objects with the same underlying NumPy array, as you can see here:

```
>>> s1array = s1.array.to_numpy()
>>> s2array = s2.array.to_numpy()
>>> s1array is s2array, id(s1array), id(s2array)
(True, 123145143806352, 123145143806352)
```

Since `s1` and `s2` are references to the same NumPy array, changing one changes the other.

But when you do this:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2.0])
s2 = s1.astype('int64', copy=False)
```

`s1` is a now type `float64`:

```
>>> s1.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

so converting its type to `int64` creates a new array:

```
>>> s1array = s1.array.to_numpy()
>>> s2array = s2.array.to_numpy()
>>> s1array is s2array, id(s1array), id(s2array)
(False, 123145146671920, 123145146285680)
```

and therefore modifying one of them doesn't modify the other.